# increase the value of a variable for each time an if condition is met in java

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm a beginner in java programming and I'm using a GUI builder. I'm making a simple text scramble-type of program and what I want to happen is that each time I input a word from a list of labels, the word will be appended to a text area and a certain value (which is initialized to 0) is increased by 1; Once the value reaches 5, a message box will appear and another JFrame form is called(will add this portion later).

When I input the first word, the value does increase by 1. Now my problem here is that each time I input another word, the value just stays at 1. I'm using an if-else statement and I tried doing it with a switch statement but to no avail.

Here's the code I put in the submit button

```
private void btnSubmitActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
String wordinp = txtfield1.getText();
int v=0;

if (wordinp.equals("bar")){
 txtarea1.append(label1.getText());
 label1.setVisible(true);
 v=v+1;
 labelval.setText(Integer.toString(v));
}

else if (wordinp.equals("bare")){
 txtarea.append(label2.getText());
 label2.setVisible(true);
 v=v+1;
 labelval.setText(Integer.toString(v));
}

else if (wordinp.equals("")||wordinp.equals(" ")){
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please input word");
}

else {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid word");
}

if (v==2){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Congrats!");
}
}
```

Is there any way to get the value to increase each time I input a new word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable v is locally inside the method. To count the number of values (words) inserted, you need you to declare your variable either as instance variable or static variable.

The advantage (dis-advantage) of the static variable is it will maintain the value as long as your class is loaded. In case of instance variable, you can count the number of words inserted with each instance.

```
private int v;
private static int v;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a local variable, which you initialize at value 0 each time, and increase with 1.

Instead of a local variable, use an instance variable, and don't reset it to 0 each time you enter your actionPerformed